# At most how many user-defined conversion operator can be implicitly applied during an implicit type conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, g++4.8

According to the working draft N3337 (the most similar draft to the published ISOC++11 standard) the answer is at most one.

*N3337*:

> At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion
> function) is implicitly applied to a single value.
>
> ```
> [ Example:
>
> struct X {
>     operator int();
> };
>
> struct Y {
>     operator X();
> };
>
> Y a;
> int b = a; // error
>            // a.operator X().operator int() not tried
>
> int c = X(a); // OK: a.operator X().operator int()
>
> —end example ]
> ```

But according to the result of compiling *main.cpp* with *gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4* and running *a.out* with the quoted statements in *Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS*, the answer is not at most one.

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
    
struct As
{
    operator int(){ std::cout<<"operator As::int()"<<std::endl; return 1; }
};

struct Bs
{
    operator int(){ std::cout<<"operator Bs::int()"<<std::endl; return As(); }
};
    
int main()
{
     int i=Bs();
    
     return 0;
}
```

compiling and running from terminal:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
$ ./a.out
```

the result (output):

```
operator Bs::int()
operator As::int()
```

Did I misunderstand something or is N3337 wrong or does gcc contains a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no double conversions getting executed here.

You have two individual conversions taking place, in two separate places.

One conversion is in `B::operator int()`.

The second conversion is in your `main()`.

Let's try to think through this logically:

Remove main() entirely from your translation unit. Do you see any double conversions?

No.

Now, let's create a header file containing the following bits, call it `structures.H`:

```
struct As
{
    operator int();
};

struct Bs
{
    operator int();
};
```

Now, create a `structures.C` file, containing the contents of each one of these operators:

```
#include <structures.H>

B::operator int(){ std::cout<<"operator As::int()"<<std::endl; return 1; }
A::operator int(){ std::cout<<"operator Bs::int()"<<std::endl; return As(); }
```

Ok, do you still see any double-conversions here? No.

Now, create your main.C:

```
#include <structures.H>

int main()
{
     int i=Bs();

     return 0;
}
```

Do you see any double conversions taking place here? No, even though what we have now, with the two translation units, the same exact code you started with.

Comment: I understand. Only one user defined conversion operator is implicitly called in the expression "int i=Bs()". ("int i=Bs().operator int()")

But another user defined conversion operator is implicitly called in the expression "return As()". ("return As().operator int()")

So two user-defined conversion operators are implicitly applied. Not in the same expression, but the quoted sentence doesn't read anything about single expression. It reads only about single value.
We could say that the values of the different calls were different values, but then the statement "int b = a;" would be valid also.

Comment: @DánielSándor - review the fact that I gave an explicit example whose actual code is logically AND structurally identical to yours, except that two separate translation units are used. When the compiler is compiling the main.cpp translation unit, it has no knowledge of what's in other one. It makes no sense for the same identical code to be valid, or not, depending on whether another chunk of code is visible in the same translation unit. So, although it is not explicitly stated, as such, it's pretty clear that this is the case.

Comment: Sorry, should it be `return As();` instead of `return 0;` ??? Otherwise, I don't see how `A::operator int()` is called?

Answer (score 2):

`int i=Bs();` invokes `Bs::operator int()` implicitly.

`return As()` invokes `As::operator int()` implicitly.

These are two separate expressions.